# Filter internal list of objects in a stream of List

Tags: java, java-stream

I have List of Person objects

```
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private List<Animal> animals;
}
```

Which have list of animal objects:

```
public class Animal {
    private String name;
}
```

I am trying to create a new list out of it and I am trying to extract only those Person who have a specific name

```
List<Person> filteredPeople = people.stream()
                .filter(e -> e.getName().equals("John")).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Is it possible to add one more filter and how do I access the Animal list inside the person so I can filter by the animal name - for example if any the Animals(inside Person) name is "Lucky" to also put this Person object inside the new list?

Looks like this is not a valid idea:

```
.filter(e -> e.getAnimals().stream().filter(f -> f.getName().equals("lucky")))
```

Comment: Use `anyMatch` instead of `filter` like `filter(e -> e.getAnimals().stream().anyMatch(f -> f.getName().equals("lucky")))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by

```
persons.stream()
    .filter(p -> p.getName.equals("John") || p.getAnimals().stream().anyMatch(a -> a.getName.equals("lucky")))
    .collect(Collectors.toList())
```